# RefreshScope is not refreshing HessianProxyFactoryBean

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator, hessian

My configuration class where I initialize the hessian bean

```
@RefreshScope
@Configuration // @Component also not working
public class HessianConfiguration {

    @Value("${sample.hessian.url}")
    private String sampleUrl;

    @Bean
    public HessianProxyFactoryBean initSampleBean() {

        HessianProxyFactoryBean invoker = new HessianProxyFactoryBean();
        invoker.setServiceUrl(sampleUrl);
        invoker.setServiceInterface(Sample.class);
        return invoker;
    }
}
```

And a sample component class where I use the bean.

```
@RefreshScope
@Component
public class SampleService {


    @Autowired
    Sample sample;

    public String doRemoteOperation(String value){

    return sample.doRemoteOperation(value);
    }
    }
```

`sample.hessian.url` is retrieved from spring config server.

But after changing the value of `sample.hessian.url` and calling "refresh" endpoint, the autowired sample bean is still trying to hit the old url value.

What am I doing wrong here ?

Comment: One possible workaround I found is to use the 'restart' endpoint. _But that  is not refresh scope_.